# Is one allowed to render his Esrog invalid once he is done with it?

Tags: halacha, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, invalid-pasul

Is one allowed to render his Esrog invalid on Hosha’ana Rabbah (or Shmini Atzeres outside of Eretz Yisrael) once he is done with it, (or even before that, if there is another Esrog he can use), and if he did so on purpose, would he be allowed to eat it on Shmini Atzeres, according to the those (such as the Ta”z, OC 665) who permit eating the Esrog on Shmini Atzeres when it became invalid?

Comment: Why might that be prohibited?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Maybe it violates the issue of Muktzeh

Comment: I don't see why that is strange. Invalid things have different rules all the time